# Install old version horde 3 in debian

Tags: linux, debian, horde

I need install old version Horde/webmail on Debian Wheezy, apt-get install is no more avaible, and be pear is installed Horde 5.

It's a fresh install Debian 7, please only old versions, I don't want install Horde 5.

Where are horde3 packages, or how can I do to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> » Where are horde3 packages, or how can I do to install it ? «

The old archive : http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/

horde(1) http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/h/horde/

horde2 http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/h/horde2/

horde3 http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/h/horde3/

Installing a downloaded package : # `gdebi [package.deb]`

---

Comment: Another way, installing from source it's very easy because horde webmail is PHP program, see http://www.algoritmo.fr/instalar-el-antiguo-horde-webmail-sin-ajax-en-servidor-linux/